# Text input changes style after changing color with jquery (.css method)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the background color of a text input field with

`$('input[name=testname]').css({"background-color": "#ffffff"});`

but after that the style of the textbox is changed [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flh4R.png)  (the right one is the changed one)

Seems to only happen in Firefox, is there a workaround for that?

Edit: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GE8h7/3/)

The first textinput has different style than the second. (Not in Chrome, here, just in Firefox 25.0.1) [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2A9J.png) is what it looks like here.

Edit 2: i corrected the color, this even happens, if the new color is the same as the old color.

Comment: This question needs a demo that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Added a link that reproduces the problem for me.

Comment: Which is because of default border's of text boxes because their style's are set to inset if you change the border-type for your input boxes it will be fixed... ;)

Comment: @VivekVikranth Yea the default border of input text is the inset `ThreeDFace`. However when you change this style it will still not use the same layout as the other. I've tryed to change the border independently, but still it is not as the 'normal' one. Which uses a gradient on the left, right and bottom border. Also the user-select effect does not work anymore.

Comment: @nkmol ha ha yea but now a [simple trick](http://jsfiddle.net/VivekNadar/GE8h7/13/) for it(sample) hope this will work.. :) removing background by css.

Comment: But by removing the background completely i can't assign a color to it anymore.

Comment: @JohnSmith  [check it now](http://jsfiddle.net/VivekNadar/GE8h7/22/) by css function it won't effect add style by `attr()`

Comment: @VivekVikranth You change both the input field. Ofcourse they will be the same then ^^ Only the `input[name="test"]` changes(is actually the 'wrong' one), the other should not be needed to modify.

Comment: @nkmol check the previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really strange behavior. I can't really find the source of this problem... I could find the source code of the default input field(in which it changes), but could not find the css source of the normal look of it.

---

### Solution 1

However i can force the input field the look like the default input field:

```
.changeBg
{
    background-color: white;

    border-radius: .18em;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #abadb3;
    border-left-color: #e2e3ea;
    border-bottom-color: #e3e9ef;
    border-right-color: #dbdfe6;

    padding: 2.23px;
}

.changeBg:hover
{
    border-top-color: #3d7bad;
    border-bottom-color: #b7d9ed;
    border-right-color: #a4c9e3;
    border-left-color: #b5cfe7;
}
```

Where i just used an class which changes the css background:

```
$('input[name=test]').addClass('changeBg');
```

*Note that is only a fallback for Firefox*

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GE8h7/25/)

**Update**

You may want to use `@-moz-document url-prefix() { }` to only target firefox for this fallback.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GE8h7/26/)

**It also seems to happen on chrome, just with plain css**

---

### Solution 2

As this not only occurs to firefox and every browser has it own markup, you might as well create one input markup for every browser.

This way you do not have to specify ever markup for every browser.

Comment: Well, it seems that the implementations are a bit flawed. (Meaning i think the (default-)style shouldn't change after changing the color only). But this seems to be a good workaround, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default: all form elements are styled by user-agent(browser) style-sheet. If you try to override style to the elements, then user-agent **partially** (observed) or fully  (may be) remove its style-sheet**.

Just **Add border styling to element to textbox** to maintain the inconsistent look.